# 414 error with vue-typeahead + nyt api

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, typeahead

I'm building a typeahead app with Vue.js using [vue-typeahead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-typeahead) for the basic functionality. I'm making a call to the New York Times top stories API with axios. The user should input characters, at which point stories whose titles match those letters should appear.

I'm currently getting at 414 error: 414 (Request-URI Too Large) - I assume this is because I'm trying to load an f-ton of info at once.

How can I make this work?

Typeahead.vue

```js
<template>
  <main class="typeahead">
    <header>
      <div class="container header__text">
        <h1>Typeahead</h1>
        <h4>A Vue.js typeahead component using the New York Times 'top stories' API</h4>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="container typeahead__section">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" v-if="loading"></i>
      <template v-else>
        <i class="fa fa-search" v-show="isEmpty"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-times" v-show="isDirty" @click="reset"></i>
      </template>

      <input type="text"
        class="typeahead__input"
        placeholder="Start typing to find a person"
        autocomplete="off"
        v-model="query"
        @keydown.down="down"
        @keydown.up="up"
        @keydown.enter="hit"
        @keydown.esc="reset"
        @blur="reset"
        @input="update"/>

      <ul class="typeahead__results" v-show="hasItems">
        <li v-for="(item, $item) in items" :class="'typeahead__block' + activeClass($item)" @mousedown="hit" @mousemove="setActive($item)">
          <div class="typeahead__content">
            <div class="typeahead__content--name" v-text="item.title"></div>
            <div class="typeahead__content--abstract" v-text="item.abstract"></div>
            <div class="typeahead__content--url" v-text="item.url"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="typeahead__no-results" v-show="isDirty && !items.length">
        <span>No results</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import VueTypeahead from 'vue-typeahead'

export default {
  extends: VueTypeahead,
  data () {
    return {
      minChars: 3,
      src: 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=0746eeb7e32c4e6b981da53229e27ddb',
      data: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=0746eeb7e32c4e6b981da53229e27ddb').then(
      response => {
        this.data = response.data.results
      }
    )
  },
  methods: {
    onHit (item) {
      window.location.href = item.url
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I notice you have `v-model="query"` but no `query` data item.

Comment: Could you show us the content of the network request in Chrome devtool?